# how to print the output of `sfLapply` calling in R

Tags: r

I made a multi-threading calling via `sfLapply`,I print some information in the function which called in `sfLapply`,it will print information to screen if do single calling ,but can not in `sfLapply`,how can I do?for example.

```
> library(snow)
> library(snowfall)
> 
> sfInit(parallel=T,cpus=3)

snowfall 1.84-6 initialized (using snow 0.3-13): parallel execution on 3 CPUs.

> 
> test <-function(i)
+ {
+     sum = 0
+     for(n in 1:i)
+     {
+         sum = n+sum
+         print(sum)
+     }
+     print(sum)
+ }
> 
> df = c(1,2,3)
> 
> test(2) #can print some output needed
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 3
> k = sfLapply(df,test) #print nothing 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it now...There is one arguments named `slaveOutfile` can capture the output information of `sfLapply`...

Comment: I have written a C++ function that used mult-thread  for loops. But the program was crashed when two thread send the output to the R. Because R does not support it. I do not know if this problem still exist or not.